# PhpStorm dynamic class method warning

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to get PhpStorm to stop warning me about methods for a dynamically initialized class.

Here is the code for my method:

```
function create_or_update_objects ($object_name, $method_callbacks = []) {
    // grab duplicate field names used to check for existing objects
    $field = new Field();
    $duplicate_field_names = $field->fetch_duplicate_names();

    foreach ($_SESSION['objects'] as $session_object) {
        $object = new $object_name();

        // set object properties
        foreach ($session_object as $key => $value) {
            if (property_exists($object, $this->data[$key]['name'])) {
                $object->{$this->data[$key]['name']} = $value;
            }
            else {
                $object->fields[$this->data[$key]['name']] = $value;
            }
        }

        // perform object method callbacks
        foreach ($method_callbacks as $method_callback) {
            $object->$method_callback();
        }

        if ($object->exists_by_duplicate_fields($duplicate_field_names)) {
            // object already exists, update by data field names
            $object->set_id_by_duplicate_fields($duplicate_field_names);
            $object->update_by_data_names($this->data);
        }
        else {
            // object does not exist, create it
            $object->create();
        }
    }
}
```

PhpStorm is giving me warnings about the following methods not found:

- exists_by_duplicate_fields
- set_id_by_duplicate_fields
- update_by_data_names
- create

I am aware that I can use `/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */` above every single line - but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*What I would do:*

1. Create an abstract class.
2. Add missing methods in your abstract class. They should be abstract or put real implementation with a correct return.
3. Above line `$object = new $object_name();` add this PHPDoc instruction:
   `/** @var PARENT_CLASS $object */` - just replace `PARENT_CLASS` with a real class

*Example:*

```
abstract class MyParent {
   public $fields;

   abstract public function exists_by_duplicate_fields($duplicate_field_names);
   abstract public function set_id_by_duplicate_fields($duplicate_field_names);
   abstract public function update_by_data_names($data);
   abstract public function create();
}
```

And then somewhere in your code:

```
/** @var MyParent $object */
$object = new $object_name();
```

*Notes:*

1. You can also add `/** @var Field[] */` above `public $fields;` It should help PhpStorm to understand how to treat `$fields` member every time, when you use it.
2. It would be good if all that classes with names `$object_name` could actually be inherited from a `PARENT_CLASS`.
3. You can replace abstract methods with implementation if needed.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm going with. It's very helpful to have this abstract class because it gives me a clear indication of what methods and properties are required for any object utilized by this helper method.